# How is the order of Docker layers defined?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

All

I think that the fsLayers of Manifest describes layers of Docker images as blow.

```
"fsLayers": [
   {
      "blobSum": "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
   },
   {
      "blobSum": "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
   },
   {
      "blobSum": "sha256:cc8567d70002e957612902a8e985ea129d831ebe04057d88fb644857caa45d11"
   },
   {
      "blobSum": "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
   }
],
```

However, I wonder where the order of each layers is defined.
I guess that the order of each layers is defined in history filed of Manifest as below.

```
"history": [
   {
      "v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"e45a5af57b00862e5ef5782a9925979a02ba2b12dff832fd0991335f4a11e5c5\",\"parent\":\"31cbccb51277105ba3ae35ce33c22b69c9e3f1002e76e4c736a2e8ebff9d7b5d\",\"created\":\"2014-12-31T22:57:59.178729048Z\",...omit...
```

If so, I guess that history id is associated with layer id.However, the "id" filed described in history field is different form blobSum in fsLayers.

Would you tell me how the order of each layers is defined?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [v2 schema](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2). Not only is v1 deprecated, but v2 makes it easier to select the configuration blob separately from the rest of the filesystem layers. To get a v2 manifest, include the Accept header when talking to the registry API:

```
Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
```

The layer order depends on whether you are looking at schema v1 or schema v2. With schema v2, the order of the layers is from the base image listed first to the most recent layer listed last. With schema v1 this order is reversed (see the [v2 docs on the layers](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/#image-manifest-field-descriptions)).

Attempting to lineup the layers with the history requires you to filter out the steps that do not create a filesystem layer. E.g. steps like CMD, ENTRYPOINT, ENV, etc only modify the image configuration which is packaged as a single blob, and won't appear as an additional filesystem layer.